# Javascript sorting string

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have array `['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A']`
and i want to sort into `['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A']`.
how to solve it using javascript ?

Comment: What exactly is your logic for sorting it that way? How do you plan to distinguish between this `'A'` and that `'A'`, for example?

Comment: You have to show at least **some** effort that you have tried to solve the problem before asking a question here. No one is going to just do it for you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i think the different of them is index

Comment: What do you mean you *think*? If you can't clearly express your sorting requirements to us, it's going to be more-or-less impossible to write them in JS.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine 
I've tried it but it's still an error, and I think it becomes unnecessary. sorry if I made a mistake

Comment: Then provide a [mcve] demonstrating that, it might also help to clarify what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to sort alphabetical by twos, and then repeat that until there are none left. Would that be accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this is not a `sorting` but a generation of a new array that accomplish your output, in that case, you could do something like this:

**1)** First filter all `A` and all `B` on different arrays.

**2)** Then create a new array where progressively you put two elements (or the quantity available) of each of the previous filtered arrays.

```js
const input = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A'];

let arrA = input.filter(x => x === 'A');
let arrB = input.filter(x => x === 'B');
let res = [];

for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(arrA.length, arrB.length); i += 2)
{
    res.push(...arrA.slice(i, i + 2), ...arrB.slice(i, i + 2));
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

In the case you need a more generic approach, you can use next one, or take the answer made by **Nina Scholz**

```js
const input = ['D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'];

let groups = input.sort().reduce(
    (acc, curr) => {
        acc[curr] = [...(acc[curr] || []), curr];
        return acc;
    },
    {}
);

let maxLength = Math.max(...Object.values(groups).map(group => group.length));

let res = [];

for (let i = 0; i < maxLength; i += 2)
{
    Object.values(groups).forEach(
        group => res.push(...group.slice(i, i + 2))
    );
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sorting with map and use a group for every value, which has the same value for each two values of the same.

```js
var array = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A'],
    groups = Object.create(null),
    result = array
        .map((value, index) => ({
            value,
            index,
            group: (value in groups ? ++groups[value] : (groups[value] = 0)) >> 1
        }))
        .sort((a, b) => a.group - b.group || a.value.localeCompare(b.value) || a.index - b.index)
        .map(o => array[o.index]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: wow .. thank you so much

Comment: Wow, you take the effort to make a generalized version, good one! +1